# How to show the external web page content in the iframe?

Tags: html, iframe

i am working on php site. i want to show the web page content of external site in my site. Is there any solution to show only content of external site web page in my site.

Your solution will be appreciated.
 Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for jQuery, CSS even PHP if the site isn't preventing itself from being iframed.

iframe simply works like this:

```
<iframe src="http://google.com" ...></iframe>
```

If the site is preventing being iframed, you may want to use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php), then display the data retrieved in a DIV or other non-iframe element.

Comment: You mean "if the site isn't preventing itself from being iframed"?

Comment: @Jared sorry for my bad english :(